# How to iterate over each active GamePad in XNA

Tags: input, xna

I'm working on my first multiplayer XNA game, and I need to be able to check input from each active [`GamePad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.gamepad.aspx) on an Xbox360 or PC so that I don't have to copy and paste the same code for four different controllers.

I've looked at the [`SignedInGamer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.signedingamer_members%28v=XNAGameStudio.31%29.aspx), and [`SignedInGamerCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.signedingamercollection_members%28v=XNAGameStudio.31%29.aspx) , but none of them have a reference to the specific `GamePad`.

I'd like to do something like the snippet below, but modified so that it can be used in a loop for all current players so that I can get input for each of them.  `PlayerIndex` has "One", "Two", "Three", and "Four".

```
GamePadState gS = GamePad.GetState(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.PlayerIndex.One);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `GetState`, the state structure will contain the property `IsConnected`. If it is false, the controller is disconnected. You can iterate over states of all active controllers using code like this:

```
for (PlayerIndex i = PlayerIndex.One; i <= PlayerIndex.Four; i++) {
    GamePadState state = GamePad.GetState(i);
    if (state.IsConnected) {
        // TODO: Process state
    }
}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of fixing a common bug in your code. Take care to use `<=` and *not* `<` in your condition. Using the latter will cause the fourth controller to not work (and will cause your game to fail peer-review - this problem is listed in http://create.msdn.com/en-US/resources/help/peer_review_evil_checklist).

Comment: @AndrewRussell Thanks for correction! Turns out it's very popular mistake. :D